# How to update a variable used in a condition which is initialized on script load with Javascript (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, conditional-statements

```js
var foo = true;

// foo here is not being updated when set to false
if(foo) {
    // and this will always work
    $("#bar").on("click", function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
}

$("#set").on("click", function() {
    alert("foo is now false");
    foo = false;
});
```

```html
<p id="bar">bar</p>
<input type="button" id="set" value="set to false" />
```

If I put `if(foo)` inside function, it works fine.

But the situation here is that there are more conditions to be checked on multiple mouse actions, I would have to write the same `if` check for each action...

```js
$("#bar").on("mouseover", function() {
    if(foo && bar && baz && qux) {
        // do job A
    }
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    if(foo && bar && baz && qux) {
        // do job B
    }
}).on("click", function() {
    if(foo && bar && baz && qux) {
        // do job C
    }
}).on("dblclick", function() {
    if(foo && bar && baz && qux) {
        // do job D
    }
});
```

So how can I write the `if` only once with updated foo to make this work? [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AT6RT/)

Comment: It has to be done inside the click if you want it to conditionally do something on each click.

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this :

```
var foo = true;

var check = function() {
     if(foo === true) //Add here your multiple checks
         return true;
    else
        return false;
}

$("#bar").on("click", function() {
    if(check())
        alert("hello");
});

$("#set").on("click", function() {
    alert("foo is now false");
    foo = false;
});
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/AT6RT/1/).

The jquery isn't parsed, but only execute functions, so you must check the var in a function or exec a new function to check the global var.

Comment: uhmmm...saves a little bit work, but I still need to `check()` on each mouse action.

Answer (score 2):

Move your if condition inside the click handler:

```
$("#bar").on("click", function() {
    if(foo) { alert("hello");}
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AT6RT/2/)**

Note that if the conditions are the same in all of your events, you can string the events together in your `.on()` call like:

```
$('#bar').on('mouseover mouseout click dblclick', function(e) {
    if(foo && bar && baz && qux) {
        switch(e.type){
            case 'mouseover':
                // thing 1
            break;
            case 'mouseout':
                // thing 2
            break;
            case 'click':
                // thing 3
            break;
            case 'dblclick':
                // thing 4
            break;
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: _If I put if(foo) inside function, it works fine. But the situation here is that there are more conditions to be checked on multiple mouse actions, I would have to write the same if check for each action..._ (quotted)

Comment: @soyuka - not if the conditions are the same. With `.on()` you can string the events together like `$('#element').on('mouseover mouseout click dblclick', function() {`

Comment: I thought I did mention this...`If I put if(foo) inside function, it works fine.` I need a better solution for my real situation here so I don't write `if` for each mouse action.

Comment: @user1643156 - see my comment to soyuka above your comment.

Comment: OMG my mistake, I did not see it like that !

Comment: your comment on @soyuka. but there are different jobs to be done on each action. can't just put them together.

Comment: @user1643156 - well according to your question all the checks are the same. E.g. `if(foo && bar && baz && qux)` for each event.

Comment: the conditions are the same. but different jobs to be done for each mouse action. `mouseover - do job A`, `click - do job B`...

Comment: Again, you didn't note that in your question, however if that's the case then there's no way to reduce your code by any great amount.

Comment: @j08691 sure there is. :) [well, maybe not reduce the number of lines, but it is certainly more DRY]

Comment: after all...I have to put `if` inside function. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example, the `if (foo)` is only evaluated at initialization time, not at the time of each click so, of course, it only acts on the value of `foo` when the code runs at init time.  If you're going to check the value of `foo` at the time of the event the check has to be inside the event handler because that is the only code that actually runs at the time of the event.

You have these choices:

1. Make one set of event handlers and then evaluate `foo` inside each event handler to call the appropriate code based on the live run-time value of `foo`.
2. When you change the value of `foo`, use `.off()` to remove the previous event handlers and install new event handlers.
3. Rather than using the variable, you could change a class name on a parent object and use delegated event handling with a separate event handler for each class name value you might use.  In this way, you would use jQuery's delegated event handling logic and selector comparison to decide which event handler should be called at any given time.

You can make option 1 more efficient or more DRY by writing a common function that you use in your multiple event handlers.  But, the fact remains that if you want to check the value of a variable at the time of the event, then you have to check it inside the event handler because that is the code that runs at the time of the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Well...put multiple `if` conditions inside event handlers isn't the only option.

Here I wrapped event handlers inside a function, and as @jfriend00 suggested, I invoked `off` on `#bar` when set `foo=false`. Also, added another button to set `foo` back to `true` just to illustrate the re-activation (re-bind) of event handlers.

```js
var foo = true;

function bar() {
    if(foo) {
        $("#bar").on("click", function() {
            alert("hello");
        })/*.on("mouseover/dblclick/...")*/;
    }
}
bar();

$("#set_false").on("click", function() {
    alert("foo is now false");
    foo = false;
    // unbind mouse actions
    $("#bar").off();
});

$("#set_true").on("click", function() {
    alert("foo is now true");
    foo = true;
    // re-activate mouse actions
    bar();
});
```

**fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/AT6RT/7/